# Use service for queries in Flask application

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am working with flask and SQLAlchemy, so let's say for example i have a class User :

```
class User(UserMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = Column(String(100))
    name = Column(String(100))
```

Now in my views every time i make a query to get a user by id or by name i make a query.So i thought to make a class called userService and put all queries in it.So i could have :

```
class UserService():
  def getUserByName(self, name):
     return User.query.filter(User.name == name).first()

   def getUserById(self, id):
      return User.query.get(id)

   def getUserByEmail(self, email):
      return User.query.filter(User.email == email).first()
```

Now in my views i can call the UserService class every time i need a user.I use application factory, so my question is: Is it more efficient to instantiate the UserService object in my create_app function and then import it in my views.py file, or instantiate a new UserService object in every route in my views.py file?

Comment: I'd argue that the pythonic way would be to get rid of your service class, and just use functions. None of the methods require state, so could just be static methods, and that leaves you with a class of only static methods, no state, and pretty much no reason at all of being a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you only need `UserService` class for namespace so you don't need to create the instance. You can change your methods to staticmethods or create a module that contains these functions:

```
# userservice.py
class UserService():
    @staticmethod
    def getUserByName(name):
        return User.query.filter(User.name == name).first()

# userservice.py
def getUserByName(name):
    return User.query.filter(User.name == name).first()
...
```

I would prefer the second approach, its more clean and pythonic way of doing this:

```
# views.py
import userservice
user = userservice.getUserByName(name)

# first approach
from userservice import UserService
user = UserService.getUserByName(name)
```

Comment: i thought another option of adding all methods in my model class, so do you think that would be better to create userservice.py file and add all these methods or add them to my User model as static methods?

Comment: I wouldn't prefer to add these methods to the model class. A model class can contain methods that do logic for the model itself, not database queries.